# Заполнение структуры С

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Суть такая:
имеется структура:

```
typedef struct {
    char * brand;
    int year;
} vehicle;
```

Выделяю память под неё так:

```
vehicle * car = malloc(sizeof(vehicle));
```

Если делать так:

```
car->brand = "Dodge";
car->year = 2007;
printf("%s %d", car->brand, car->year);
```

То всё работает, но если попытаться вводить с клавиатуры так:

```
printf("\nВведите марку авто: ");
scanf("%s", car->brand);
printf("\nВведите год выпуска авто: ");
scanf("%d", &car->year);
```

То будет

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

После ввода строки.

Изучаю только, просьба не кидаться, ибо разбираюсь пока в указателях.

Comment: Вы распределили память под саму структуру, однако внутри неё указатель на строку, в которую должно идти наименование, не инициализирован и показывает чёрт-те куда. Поэтому при попытке что-то записывать в указываемую им случайную область памяти и возникает segfault. А при присвоении указателю константы, насколько я помню, он изменяется на адрес этой константы, поэтому ничего страшного не происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("\nВведите марку авто: ");
scanf("%s", car->brand);
```

Вы читаете *куда-то* в какое-то неопределенное место в памяти...

Вам нужно выделить место заранее - или, например,

```
typedef struct {
    char brand[50];
    int year;
} vehicle;
```

или выделять динамически -

```
car->brand = malloc(50);   
scanf("%s", car->brand);
```

Понятно, что 50 я взял "с потолка", вы должны брать разумные значения и при считывании строки обеспечить отсутствие переполнения буфера. Так что лучше воспользоваться функцией `fgets`, тем более что она считывает любую строку - в том числе с пробелами, чего не обеспечивает ваш способ ввода.

Comment: Еще можно массив переменной длины использовать, так будет всего один вызов malloc.